# Corrupting the system by completely filling the `/`

Tags: rhel, disk-usage, corruption

Is it possible to corrupt a RHEL7 system (specifically an XFS filesystem) by completely filling it with data?

I can imagine bad things happening if disk writes fill to complete but I would also hope that there are protections in place. Would it matter whether `/` fills up or another partition?

Comment: From the help center [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): 
To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …[...]  * There is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”  * You are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Comment: I see how this questions fits that template but on the other hand it doesn't fit under 'subjective' IMO. If after filling disk the system stops working that's an objective fact and it either does or does not.

Comment: You do not exactly corrupt a filesystem, but you may corrupt data, for instance, a database living in the same partition that is filled.

Comment: @zagrimsan It does seem to me to be an actual problem to know how important it is to prevent this from happening. Depending on the answer you would act differently.

Comment: @BobJansen it was more of a note to you, myself I can't say if it will be closed or not. However I think your question does contain the element that tends to make answers start with "it depends...". ^Rui F Ribeiro pretty much nails it already, but to get answers with any more depth you'd need to describe the case in more detail.

Comment: After reading https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/477/44760 I think I'll adapt with you guys who supported the Q. Fine by me, really :)

Comment: You can expect some processes to die without having a chance to close their files.  The results can range from harmless to disastrous, depending on what OS you're running, what filesystem you're filling up, what processes got killed, what they were trying to do when they died, etc.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as too broad. "...or another partition" leaves this open to "/some/java/app" filesystem filling up, doing from zero to some "damage" to that app. Also, what if the system is stateless; filling up root may do nothing, or may do something.

Comment: The best possibility I see here is the question of whether you can damage an XFS filesystem by filling it up. I would hope that the authors have that as one of their test scenarios; are you looking for evidence of that?

Comment: The root file system normally reserves 5% file space to ensure that the system doesn't "brick" Other file systems can run out of space and cause applications to crash but not the system. Corruption could occur to applications residing on the system but not on the system itself. To safe guard against this on Linux systems, thinly provisioned logical volumes should be considered along with auto-expansion and alerting for low disk space. Sand-boxing and such things a control groups and selinux/apparmor should also be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad Things(TM) may happen if a filesystem is 100% full (or perhaps 105% on account of the `root` reserved space). Specific cases I have seen (though these are not for XFS):

- 100% full NTFS partition (we had warned the user not to run their laptop that full but they did for months...) ended up with filesystem loops so when you tried to backup data off of that 300G disk you could fill a 3T disk or whatever because loops.
- Some linux virtual machines with near 100% full disks due to a bug began writing end-of-partition bits back at the beginning of the partition, thus destroying various important bits that happen to live there.

So yes if there is a bug you could end up with a corrupt filesystem; as a precaution on test systems or during bake-in one might completely fill the disk to see what happens. Usually however the partition just fills up and writes fail without any OS or filesystem corruption (of course application software may then be Very Unhappy(TM) as the programmers never tested what happens when writes fail... e.g. `stunnel` stopped processing application data when it could not write logs)

(There are legitimate cases where a filesystem might be run 100% full, e.g. a database might want all the space, or it's a (mostly?) read-only partition with scads of genome data, etc.)

Otherwise there are typically no protections in place; usually some sort of monitoring gets setup that warns when a partition is X% full, or shows a large change in space consumed. Often these things can be predicted in advance based on growth over time: it's better to send an email on say Thursday ("partition X will hit 90% in three days...") than an emergency page at 3AM on a Sunday (90% full - error! error! error!).

Answer (score 1):

> Would it matter whether / fills up or another partition?

There's [a question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384168/server-poweroff-after-root-partition-full) about CentOS 7 (RHEL 7) stating that a full `/` partition causes the system to power off. I have never experienced that myself. Nonetheless, yes: it can certainly matter if a partition or volume is full: imagine not being able to write to log files, create temporary files, write to a database, upload files into a home directory, or acquire updates. It's a broad question, and there's a lot to imagine! Any trouble will be related to the purpose and configuration of the partition or volume.

> I would also hope that there are protections in place

Use the audit system to alert designated staff members when the audit storage volume approaches capacity. The auditd service can be configured to take an action when disk space starts to run low. Edit the file `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` to use the following configuration directive.

```
space_left_action = email
```

Possible values for the action to perform are described in the "auditd.conf" man page. These include:

- ignore
- syslog
- email
- exec
- suspend
- single
- halt

Email sent to the root account is typically aliased to the administrators of the system, who can take appropriate action. (See `/etc/aliases` and  `man newaliases`.)